# Private node crashing and rejecting connections after a few minutes

Tags: error, private-mode

I have two nodes, a private one and a public one. After importing a snapshot in my private node, I’m finishing to sync it connecting to my public node, but it's worker crashes after a few minutes. After that, it even rejects a new connection from the public node using `connect address <private_node_id>:9732`, and I have to relaunch the private node, and sometimes even run again `trust peer <public_node_id>` and `trust address <public_node_id>:9732`.

In the case it's important, I'm running both nodes in AWS, using t3a.medium and EBS.

Error in the private node:

```
Sep 17 01:31:52 - node.validator.bootstrap_pipeline: Unexpected error (validator):
Sep 17 01:31:52 - node.validator.bootstrap_pipeline: Error, dumping error stack:
Sep 17 01:31:52 - node.validator.bootstrap_pipeline:   Fetch of operations BKzPAP6d4MPKsiAkzfQ2nA6H8cLQg7XC4m6xhoZ6qUK4WbymGHZ:3 timed out
Sep 17 01:31:52 - node.validator.bootstrap_pipeline:   Fetch of operations BKzPAP6d4MPKsiAkzfQ2nA6H8cLQg7XC4m6xhoZ6qUK4WbymGHZ:2 timed out
Sep 17 01:31:52 - node.validator.bootstrap_pipeline:   Fetch of operations BKzPAP6d4MPKsiAkzfQ2nA6H8cLQg7XC4m6xhoZ6qUK4WbymGHZ:1 timed out
Sep 17 01:31:52 - node.validator.bootstrap_pipeline:   Fetch of operations BKzPAP6d4MPKsiAkzfQ2nA6H8cLQg7XC4m6xhoZ6qUK4WbymGHZ:0 timed out
Sep 17 01:31:52 - node.validator.bootstrap_pipeline:
Sep 17 01:31:52 - main: validator-peer_1 : Worker crashed [validator-peer_1]:
Sep 17 01:31:52 - main:                    Fetch of operations BKzPAP6d4MPKsiAkzfQ2nA6H8cLQg7XC4m6xhoZ6qUK4WbymGHZ:0 timed out
Sep 17 01:31:52 - main:                    Fetch of operations BKzPAP6d4MPKsiAkzfQ2nA6H8cLQg7XC4m6xhoZ6qUK4WbymGHZ:1 timed out
Sep 17 01:31:52 - main:                    Fetch of operations BKzPAP6d4MPKsiAkzfQ2nA6H8cLQg7XC4m6xhoZ6qUK4WbymGHZ:2 timed out
Sep 17 01:31:52 - main:                    Fetch of operations BKzPAP6d4MPKsiAkzfQ2nA6H8cLQg7XC4m6xhoZ6qUK4WbymGHZ:3 timed out(2019-09-17T01:31:52-00:00)
```

Error appearing in the public node after trying a new connection to the private node:

```
/mainnet.sh admin-client connect address <private_node_ip>:9732
Error:
  Rejected peer connection: rejected socket connection.
```